# ADDING A STRING IN FRONT OF CERTAIN ROWS IN A SUBTITLE FILE (srt)

Tags: string

I have a subtitle file, like this :

[...]

11
00:01:23,683 --> 00:01:26,151
Policeman:
Henry!

12
00:01:26,153 --> 00:01:27,853
Get out of here!

13
00:01:27,855 --> 00:01:32,091
Just go home
and leave this all to me!

14
00:01:32,093 --> 00:01:33,258
Go!

etc

and I want, in front of every talk ( Henry, get out of here, just go home and leave this to me, go! etc) to put the string " {\an8} " so as for every subtitle to appear yellow and at the top of the screen.

How can I do it ? Because manually is impossible given that there are some 800 subtitle in every episode.

Comment: Which programming language are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Use the Split function in your favorite programming language to split each line over a space character.  Hopefully your programming language allows you to limit the number of splits to 4 so that the forth item in the split contains the entire subtitle.

Take the resulting array and add your string to the fourth item in the array.  Then, merge the four strings in the array back into a single string.

Do this for each line in your original file, writing the resulting string out to a new file.

Comment: Well, I am not a programmer... :-(((((
I just want to know whether I could do it throygh simple tools of Microsoft Word, or through Wordpad or Notepad++
Sorry but I have not the slighest idea about arrays or programming languages... :-(((((

Comment: I guess I am in the wrong place asking the wrong people.
Seems like a programming site.
Sorry to bother you anyway..!